# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13405/41070).**

Arqade is scheduled for an election [next week, June 3rd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/6). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until June 3rd at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 17):

You (a moderator) and another community member both answer a question. The other answer is well written but (objectively) incorrect, and has gathered a similar amount of upvotes to yours. What do you do?

Comment: Addendum: the question you answered is a regular site question, not a meta question

Answer (score 13):

Moderators are not selected because they are domain experts in certain tags, but it so happens that you are an expert in one such tag. You see that several members of the community have elected to close a question as a duplicate, but you see that the duplicates don't actually answer the question as stated, nor do they provide a useful signpost for the asker. How do you proceed?

Answer (score 13):

A relatively new community member has shown misgivings about an established site policy and has a suggestion to change the policy. Their suggested change (posted on meta) isn't being well received by community regulars and the debate appears to be drifting in an unfriendly direction.

How do you approach and respond to this situation?

Answer (score 13):

The Bridge, our main chat room, is one of the most active on the network. Do you see the moderation of Arqade's chat rooms as part of your duties? If you're not active in chat currently, would you consider it part of the job to keep an eye on what's going on there?

Comment: I'd almost add TIF to this as well, perhaps.

Comment: @Ash Yeah I put it as 'moderation of Arqade's chat rooms' rather than make it Bridge-specific for this reason, there are always other game/topic specific rooms around at any one time too.

Answer (score 11):

There is a high-rep user who is very active on the site, but frequently uses strong language which violates the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) in their comments. When you warned them, they replied stating that the questions are of low quality which is why they left those comments. They also threatened to quit the site. Despite the warning, they continue to post similar comments. What steps, if any, will you take in order to address this situation? What if the comments were on Meta instead of main? Does that change your approach at all?

Answer (score 11):

We have a very active chat community, but at the end of the day, it is a very small part of our actual community. Sometimes, people discuss site policy in chat as if ruling decisions can be made there, instead of moving them to meta. How would you deal with this? How much value do you place on chat as a place of community consensus?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 7):

A moderator performs an action on a post that you strongly disagree with. Nobody has communicated with the moderator regarding this action, or disagreed with it through voting, posting on meta, or any other means. How do you react?